# Refresh Dataframe created by writing to Parquet files in append mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a way that I can refresh a dataframe that is being created by appending to the parquets in `pyspark`?

Basically I am writing to `parquet` in append mode, data that I get daily.
If I want to check the `parquet` file created I load it up in `pyspark` and do a count of the data. However if new data is appended to the parquet and I try a count again on the dataframe without reloading the dataframe I do not get the updated count. Basically, I have to create a new dataframe everytime there are any changes to my parquet file. Is there a way in Spark, where the changes are automatically loaded once my parquet is updated?

Comment: Some code snippet would help.

Comment: @Asaf There is no issue with the code, the code works fine, I want to know if there is some config property that can help me solve my problem.

Comment: Did you try `REFRESH table_name`?